# Is it the best practice to make the whole webpage clickable?

Tags: user-behavior, navigation, popup

I have a lead generation webpage which has a pop-up form which appears wherever clicked on the page.

Is is it good to make the entire webpage clickable or only buttons & icons should be clickable?

Comment: Depends what the webpage looks like. If you make it look like one giant button, then sure why not. As a general rule though, probably not a good user experience. Especially on mobile where people touch everywhere and don't expect something to happen unless it's obviously a button or link, etc.

Comment: And why in the world would you'd do that?. To be honest, if I saw something like that I would run away from your website and would never return.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds very internet-marketingisky to be honest. It is not a standard practice and definitely isn't a best practice. When interacting with or browsing webpages users will do other things with their mouse (or touchpad/touch). They might click and drag to highlight text while reading, might swipe up and down to scroll, pinch to zoom etc even on read only websites. All these could easily become a click by accident.

If everything is clickable there is no reason for buttons to exist on your website. As a lead gen web page i think you should aim to gain the users' trust. To do this give them a decent user experience where things are what they seem to be.

Comment: Agreed, think of it as a user: If everything you do brings an unexpected behavior that encourages you to give personal information to the site; I know I would close the tab and never come back as it's a bad experience and makes me not trust the company behind it.

Comment: I would just like to reemphasize the word "TRUST" in this answer. Lead generation fails miserably without trust. It can even create active detractors.

Answer (score 3):

> If everything is clickable there is no reason for buttons to exist on your website. As a lead gen web page i think you should aim to gain the users' trust. To do this give them a decent user experience where things are what they seem to be. -Ameen Akbar

Expanding on the previous answer by Ameen Akbar (I don't have rights to comment yet), one most also approach from a place of accessibility.  If a user is navigating using keyboard only, implementation of full-page click would be one of three things: nonexistent, clunky, or very annoying.

If your goal is to make sure that the user always has access to the form, no matter where they happen to be on the page, a common solution is to float a button using `position: sticky;`

[w3schools.com - positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: Could you copy and paste the relevant portions of the previous comment - or say who wrote it?  As answers get upvoted the order changes.

Comment: Edited, sorry about that.

Comment: no worries - just helps as time goes by

Answer (score 0):

Doing a User Flow diagram for Automated Marketing Campaigns is pretty important. Yes the business goals and marketing goals would be to have the users drop into the lead-gen bucket with one click but what would your users' goals be?

Some users will scroll and read everything, some users will click the first button they see and some users are going to want to check out other information on the site. So no, best practice would not be to make the whole webpage clickable, but from a UX standpoint you may also want to have other pages/areas your users can access the form.